# How can I cast or convert the result of two unix time data types to int in mySQL

Tags: mysql

This is my SQL:

```
(CURDATE() - FROM_UNIXTIME(timeaccess,'%Y-%m-%d') ) AS days_since_last_access
```

How do I cast or convert the days_since_last_access computed field to an int.

thanks

Comment: this sql statement gives you an integer value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question does not make sense.  What do you want to do?  If you just want the number of days between the two dates you can use [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) -

```
DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), FROM_UNIXTIME(timeaccess,'%Y-%m-%d')) AS days_since_last_access;
```